# How to add float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, i tried to make a simple calc and i wanted to make sure user wont be able to input values that will cause an error. Now, i dont know why but it gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ct.py", line 50, in <module>
    p = a + b
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Tried with except ValueError instead of making if and throwing every argument, and it worked, but code is messy so i tried to clean it up a little bit/ do it other, simplier way.

```
import time
def ll(a):
    return all(x in "0123456789.+-" for x in a)
def countdot(text):
    count = 0
    for c in text:
        if c == '.':
            count = count + 1
    return count
def countminus(text):
    count = 0
    for c in text:
        if c == '-':
            count = count + 1
    return count
def a1():
    a = input("Wprowadz pierwszą liczbę: ")
    err = True
    while err == False:
        if ll(a)== True and a != "." and a != "-" and a != "+" and countdot(a) <= 1 and countminus(a) <= 1:
            a = float(a)
            err = True
        else:
            print("To nie liczba!")
            b = input("Wprowadz pierwszą liczbę: ")
    return a
def b1():
    err = True
    b = input("Wprowadz drugą liczbę: ")
    while err == True:
        if ll(b)== True and b != "." and b != "-" and b != "+" and countdot(b) <= 1 and countminus(b) <= 1:
            b = float(b)
            err = False
        else:
            print("To nie liczba!")
            b = input("Wprowadz drugą liczbę: ")
    return b
repeat = True   
while repeat == True:
    print("Prosty Kalukator. Wybierz działanie: ")
    print("Dodawanie: +, Odejmowanie: -, Mnożenie: *, Dzielenie: /")
    d = input()
    while d != "+" and d != "-" and d != "*" and d != "/" :
        print("Błąd! Dodawanie: +, Odejmowanie: -, Mnożenie: *, Dzielenie: /")
        d = input()
    if d == "+" :
        a = a1()
        b = b1()
        print("Wynik działania to: ")
        p = a + b
        p = float(p)
        print(p)
```

I expected it to just add a and b "p = a + b" and it just gives me error.

Comment: Because one of them is a string. That's what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def a1():
    a = input("Wprowadz pierwszą liczbę: ")
    err = True
    while err == False:
        ...
    return a
```

This function has a bug.  `err` is `True`, so the `while` loop never runs.  The original value of `a` is returned (which is a string).

Answer (score 1):

As [juanpa.arrivillaga commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732418/how-to-add-float/55732484#comment98143389_55732418), there was a problem with one of them being a string. The correct solution was to add `a = float(a)` after the while loop instead of in the loop:

```
def a1():
    a = input("Wprowadz pierwszą liczbę: ")
    err = True
    while err == False:
        if ll(a)== True and a != "." and a != "-" and a != "+" and countdot(a) <= 1 and countminus(a) <= 1:
            err = True
        else:
            print("To nie liczba!")
            b = input("Wprowadz pierwszą liczbę: ")
    a = float(a)
    return a
```